# How to get the first value of a Linkedhashmap that is String and node

Tags: java, key, linkedhashmap

I am trying to get the first name of a linkedhashmap but its only spitting out the last one.

This is my hashmap, Im only getting the last name printed out. How do I get the first one?
Is there a way to get it linked to the key. For example "gumt" prints out Gumtäkts uni.bibliotek?

```
LinkedHashMap<String,Node> nodes = new LinkedHashMap<>();

nodes.put("gumt", new Node("Gumtäkts uni.bibliotek   ", 60.2039, 24.9638));
nodes.put("lill", new Node("Lillhoplax bibliotek     ", 60.2008, 24.8954));
nodes.put("bush", new Node("Busholmens bibliotek     ", 60.1593, 24.9207));

for (String key : nodes.keySet()) {

           
           nodes.get(key).setKey(key);

           System.out.println("[" + key + "]" + " " + nodes.get(key).getName());
}
return nodes;
```

Output:

```
[gumt] Busholmens bibliotek     
[lill] Busholmens bibliotek 
[bush] Busholmens bibliotek
```

I also have a Node class that comes into effect.
Node class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Node{

    private static String name;
    private static String key;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private static ArrayList<Node> neighbours;

    public Node(String name, double latitude, double longitude) {


        this.name = name;
        this.key = key;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.neighbours = neighbours;
    }

    public static String getName() {

        return name;
        }

    public static String getKey(){

        return key;
    }

    public void setName(String name){

        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setKey(String name){

        this.key = key;
    }

    public void addNeighbour(Node neighbour){

        this.neighbours = neighbours;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Node> getNeighbours(){

        return neighbours;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `entrySet()` instead of `keySet()`:

```java
for (Map.Entry<String, Node> entry : nodes.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Node node = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println("[" + key + "] " + node.getName());
}
```

Comment: still only getting the last one printed =/

Comment: @Sofelia - the `name` field in the `Node` class it static, meaning every time you create a new `Node` object, you're over-writing the previous `name` field. Make the `name` field not static and you should be good!

Comment: Omgosh it worked, thank you so much! I had so much trouble with that!!

Answer (score 2):

A second association map can be created to keep track the order of elements inserted.

```
public class TestFirst {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main m = new TestFirst().new Main();
        System.out.println(m.nodes.get(m.map.get(1)));
        System.out.println(m.nodes.get(m.map.get(3)));
    }
    
    class Main
    {
        int counter=0;
        LinkedHashMap<String,Node> nodes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map <Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        Main()
        {
            nodes.put("gumt", new Node("Gumtäkts uni.bibliotek   ", 60.2039, 24.9638));
            map.put(incCounter(), "gumt");
            nodes.put("lill", new Node("Lillhoplax bibliotek     ", 60.2008, 24.8954));
            map.put(incCounter(), "lill");
            nodes.put("bush", new Node("Busholmens bibliotek     ", 60.1593, 24.9207));
            map.put(incCounter(),"bush");
        }
        public int incCounter()
        {
            return ++counter;
        }
        class Node
        {
            private String name;
            private String key;
            private double latitude;
            private double longitude;
            private ArrayList<Node> neighbours;

            public Node(String name, double latitude, double longitude) {


                this.name = name;
                this.key = key;
                this.latitude = latitude;
                this.longitude = longitude;
                this.neighbours = neighbours;
            }

            public String toString()
            {
                return name+"("+latitude+","+longitude+")";
            }
            public String getName() {
                return name;
                }
            
            public String getKey(){
                return key;
            }

            public void setName(String name){
                this.name = name;
            }

            public void setKey(String name){
                this.key = key;
            }

            public void addNeighbour(Node neighbour){
                this.neighbours = neighbours;
            }

            public ArrayList<Node> getNeighbours(){
                return neighbours;
            }

          }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Gumtäkts uni.bibliotek   (60.2039,24.9638)
Busholmens bibliotek     (60.1593,24.9207)
```

Note: Check also the modifiers: `static`.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("[" + key + "]" + " " + nodes.get(key).getName())
```

In this line you are trying to print the values, which are linked to the keys i suppose. But, the `getName()` function in the class `node`, only returns the name attribute of `nodes`, which in your case is always the same, because the field `name` is defined as static in your class `Node`